# Are there any other members of Yoda's species in Legends?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Though I know about Yaddle, Minch and Oteg, I was wondering if any others are ever shown or referenced. Any unnamed members count.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are five or six members of Yoda's species identified in Canon and Legends materials. For the sake of completeness, I'm going to include the three mentioned in the question:

1. **Yoda** himself, obviously
2. **Yaddle**, the only known female member of Yoda's species:

   [image]

   Yaddle was a Jedi Master and member of the Jedi High Council in 32 BBY (*The Phantom Menace*). She stepped down from the Council after the Battle of Naboo.

These two are the only Canon members of Yoda's species; all the rest are pure Legends characters.

3. **Minch**, a Jedi Knight from c. 700 BBY:

   [image]

   Minch's only appearance is in one of the *Star Wars Tales* comic book stories, where we learn that he is responsible for creating the Dark Side cave on Dagobah. His fate after this is unknown.
4. **Vandar Tokare**, Jedi Master c. 4000 BBY

   [image]

   Master Vandar was head of the Jedi Enclave on Dantooine at the time of the Mandalorian Wars and the Jedi Civil War. He appears in the *Knights of the Old Republic* video game and comic book series. In the video game *Knights of the Old Republic II: The Sith Lords*, it is revealed that Master Vandar was killed when the Sith Lord Darth Nihilus attacked the Jedi Conclave on Katarr.
5. **An unnamed Jedi** appears in [relief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relief) in the Valley of the Jedi, in the video game *Jedi Knight: Dark Forces II*

   [image]

   It's not impossible that this is either Vandar or Oteg, since the Valley is first mentioned several thousand years after the first appearances of both characters. However, there has been no confirmation of this.
6. **Oteg**, a Jedi Master at the time of the Great Galactic War and Cold War (c. 3600 BBY):

   [image]

   Oteg appears in *The Old Rebuplic* MMORPG.

In a non-canon example, an [unproduced promo card](http://theswca.com/images-rarit/p3-front.html) for the Topps *Star Wars* Galaxy trading card game was to feature several members of Yoda's species:

[image]

The card was vetoed by Lucasfilm, but you can find a few of them floating around.

Comment: +1 We posted at almost the same time, but you included images.

Comment: The card is actually the very thing that caused me to ask. I saw it and wondered if there were any other members of the species. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Is the species canonically heavy in Jedi, or are they just the only ones considered interesting enough for us to hear about?

Comment: @Amadeus9: Sounds like a reasonable, _new_ question!

Comment: @Amadeus9 Impossible to say; Lucasfilm has historically been reticent to explore the species in any detail. All we can say with confidence is that all known members of the species have been Jedi, but that's not much of a statement

Answer (score 4):

Wookieepedia's article on [Yoda's species](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda%27s_species/Legends) also lists

- [Vandar Tokare](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vandar_Tokare) from *Knights of the Old Republic*
- an [unidentified Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Unidentified_Jedi_%28Yoda%27s_species%29) (a statue of his face is seen in *Dark Forces* media)

Answer (score 2):

In *The Mandalorian* there is The Child, a 50 year old member of Yoda's species though its origins are somewhat unclear at present.

[image: The Child in The Mandalorian]